# NetworkManager rewrites name servers in config file

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn

I have a wifi network connection that has a config file

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyNetwork.nmconnection
```

Name resolving did not work, so I added my provider's name servers.

But upon restarting, I have found the name servers that do not work.

In the meantime I used my company VPN and that could rewrite them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use the GUI: Settings > Network > (interface) > cogwheel-icon > IPv4 or 6 > DNS (auto/DHCP or not)